Flutter isn't showing the desired tflite model output
I have trained a dataset and converted it into .tflite format. But when i used this .tflite model in my flutter application, The result has a huge difference.
# Sample input data (replace with your desired values)
new_data = pd.DataFrame({'week': [1],'rainfall': [0.3], 'humidity': [74],'max temp': [24], 'min temp': [12]})

Output was: Python model prediction: 14.878789
TFLite model prediction: [14.878793]
But for the same input in the flutter application:
I/flutter (15578): Input data:
I/flutter (15578): [[1.0, 0.3, 74.0, 24.0, 12.0]]
I/flutter (15578): [[10968801.0]]

Without your code, it is hard to answer. But most likely, you didn't normalize your inputs in the flutter application before feeding them to the model while in your training your model, you must have normalized the inputs somehow.
